# To traverse rows into columns

Tags: excel, vba

I am having three columns (App, Ticket, Efforts). Task is to separate the username which accidentally gets added in Column A (App) and apply it in new column (Column D). Data as below.

```
App           Ticket    Efforts

James, lijo     

App1          23    13

App2          44    22

App3          55    33

Tom, Cruise     

App2          44    22

App1          33    42



Output Expected :


App Ticket  Efforts ColumnD

App1    23  13    James, Lijo

App2    44  22    James, Lijo

App3    55  33    James, Lijo

App2    44  22    Tom, Cruise

App1    33  42    Tom, Cruise
```

Comment: I was revolving around this                                        For currentRow = 1 To totalrows
    If (IsEmpty(Cells(currentRow, 1).Value)) Then

    Else
        Cells(currentRow, 1).Select
        offsetrow = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).row

        row = offsetrow

        i = 1
        Do While (Cells(row, 2).Value <> "")
            i = i + 1
            row = row + 1
            Cells((row - 1), 1).Value = Cells(currentRow, 1).Value

        Loop

    End If
  Next

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stick this formula in D3 and drag it down to the last row

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(B2),IF(B3<>"",D2,""),A2)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the quick turnaround :)